# Escaping while using PDO

Tags: php, security, pdo, sql-injection

I love using PDO in PHP but i don't like bind because there is addition of codes etc.. But we cannot ignore the SQL injection and other security holes.

I use this PHP wrapper class [PHP PDO Wrapper Class](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/)

I heard escaping greatly prevents from SQL injection (is it correct)?

i heard doing HTML special chars completely don't prevent SQL injection?

Can i get the way to escape the data that i get from POST ?

For example i use to insert in database like this using run statement (Using PHP wrapper class)

```
$firstname=$_POST["first_name"];
and many more variables

global $db;

$db->run(sprintf("INSERT INTO users (UserGroup, UserEmail, UserName, UserToken, UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserPassword, Verified, SignupDate, UserIP) VALUES ('1', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', 'Y', '%s', '%s')", $email, $username, md5(time()*rand(1, 9999)),$firstname, $lastname, $password, time(),$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]));
```

Is this above code vulnerable to sql injection and are there any security holes

Comment: No, this is just as vulnerable.  Please try to understand [*why*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters) string interpolation is vulnerable to SQL injection; then you will understand why your code is also vulnerable.

Comment: You don't like bind? What a strange statement.

Comment: Also, please think about what the relationship is between HTML special chars and SQL injection (hint: there is no relationship).

Comment: There is no additional code. One line to bind a parameter or one line to escape a value. It's still one line of code. Only the bind line is better. ;)

Comment: The Blue Dog actually i don't like prepared statment is there any probelm?

Comment: @user3689984: So, you don't like bind and you don't like prepared statements, yet you want your code to be secure. Yes, I'd say there's a problem somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP’s standard extensions are still quite low-level and many developers think they are smart when programing on such a low level. However, there are many libraries/frameworks out there that do a great job in abstracting these low-level action. For example, if you would use [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), you could just do something like `new User(array('UserEmail' => $email, …))` and everything else is handled by the library/framework.

Comment: @blue dog my question is how to escape it man don't jerk

Comment: @user3689984: If you prepare and bind then you don't need to escape anything, that's the whole point.

Comment: I just read that the [PHP PDO Wrapper Class you have mentioned](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) already supports abstraction for insert. So what’s wrong with `$db->insert("users", array("UserEmail"=>$email, …));`?

Comment: Gumbo yes nothign is wrong with it??i just want to know is that good enough to handle sql injection ..? thanks you read the class

Comment: @user3689984 Yes, it is. That’s the whole purpose of such an abstraction. But note that with this particular class injection is still possible via the table name as they fail to use a prepared statement when querying the table columns (see `filter` function). But it’s safe if the table names are hard-coded.

Comment: +1 gumbo thanks...they are actually hardcoded as user never set....your technique is really awesome ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking here about two kinds of injection :

1. SQL injection, which use special characters like `"` or `'` to modify the request being executed. It can be avoided by escaping the values in your request, or by preparing your statements (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks) for a complete explanation).
2. HTML injection, which use variables displayed in the HTML to inject code directly into the page. It can be avoided by using `htmlspecialchars`, and has nothing to do with SQL injection.

You can't use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent SQL injection. The simpler way to do this would be to prepare your statements (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)). Even if you don't like it, there is not that much code added and it's the most secure way to do it.

You can also use `PDO::quote` (see doc [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)). Your request **is** vulnerable, but you can just use the quote function on each parameter to secure it. I tend to find this much more verbose (compared to preparing and binding), but it you who code.

I read your library page, and didn't found the documentation that helpful, so I read the code and found that is literally extends PDO, so you can use the quote function from PDO with it (or preparing, binding, etc).

Comment: yea ok from people i found bind is essential..now i love binds...i will use bind ..

Comment: I don't care who downvote but your answer was good anyway...those who cannot answer don't have right to downvote or upvote anyway

Comment: I don't care about minor nuisances like him either, my goal is just to help…

Answer (score 1):

Your example is still vulnerable to SQL injections as you’re building the statement using user-provided data. In the resulting statement you can’t say which portions were provided by the developer and which by the user.

That’s why people suggest prepared statements and/or parameterized statements where the developer provided portion (SQL statement) and the user provided portion (data parameters) are strictly separated so that they won’t mix.

However, the [PHP PDO Wrapper Class you have mentioned](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) does already support this. Here’s an [example for your INSERT statement](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/#insert):

```
$attrs = array(
    "UserGroup"     => 1,
    "UserEmail"     => $email,
    "UserName"      => $username,
    "UserToken"     => md5(time()*rand(1, 9999)),
    "UserFirstName" => $firstname,
    "UserLastName"  => $lastname,
    "UserPassword"  => $password,
    "Verified"      => "Y",
    "SignupDate"    => time(),
    "UserIP"        => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
);
$db->insert("users", $attrs);
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense However, general practice when writing PHP. ;)

Comment: Gumbo yes good one but is it binded?? and prevented from sql injection let me know please.

Comment: @user3689984 Look at the source code: it uses PDO with prepared statements.